# How to draw polygons in a scatterplot based on any factor?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I pasted the data [here](https://pastebin.com/PJjB7QvZ):
The dataframe contains multiple observations on x and y per country. Each country is also part of a region.

Based on [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22805/how-to-draw-neat-polygons-around-scatterplot-regions-in-ggplot2), I managed to draw ploygons/clusters in the scatterplot using ggplot based on the same factor as the colors of my points are based on (i.e., country).
Here's the code I used:

```
find_hull <- function(df) df[chull(df$x, df$y), ]
hulls <- ddply(df, "country_name", find_hull)

plot <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, colour=country_name, fill=country_name)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_polygon(data = hulls, alpha = 0.5)
plot
```

But what if I want to draw the polygons based on region, and still have the color assigned by country? Just changing `country_name`to `region`when ddplying the `find_hull`function did not produce satisfying results.
I have the feeling it's because I do not fully understand yet what the `chull`function does, but I didn't manage to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ddplying the `find_hull`function was sufficient,
just had to specify `fill=region`in `geom_polygon`, and leave it unspecified in the overall `ggplot`